# Where can I suggest functionality for stack overflow?

Tags: support

I have a suggestion but it's not a question so shouldn't be asked here (if I understand correctly...).

Is there a place where suggestions can be *discussed*?

(Instead of them having to be in this question/answer format)?

Comment: It depends on what your "suggestion" is. Is it a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: Here, just use the feature-request tag!

Comment: Just a casual hint based on what I've seen happen (a lot): feature requests in the form of "this really doesn't work right, it needs to be changed. Any ideas?" won't be received well. You have to come with suggestions of your own. The most upvoted feature requests are those with diagrams and red free-hand circles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow (i.e. here) would be the place to suggest new functionality for Stack Overflow.  It should be tagged with at *least* [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

To have a well-received feature request, bear in mind that it should be:

- Clear
- Thought out
- Not something that has been suggested already (e.g. "require comments for downvotes")
- Not wide-open (e.g. "Should we add feature X?  What's the harm in doing it?  Thoughts?")
- Solve an actual problem with the site

Comment: I would also add that feature requests should solve actual problems.

Comment: The [tag info page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) says all of that and more...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  And here I was reciting much of that from memory...